# Setting up SVN Server to work on Apache 2.2.22 (64 bits - already installed) and Windows 7 (64 bits)

Tags: php, apache, svn, 64-bit

I'm trying to setup a SVN Server 1.7.5 on my development workstation which has the following tools **already working**:

- [Apache Server 2.2.22 **(64 bits)** - VC10 from Apache Lounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/binaries/httpd-2.2.22-win64.zip)
- [PHP 5.4.3 VC9-TS **(64 bits)** from Anindya's Blog](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/)
- XDebug 2.2.0 VC9 for PHP 5.4.x TS **(64 bits)** from Xdebug.org
- MySQL CE 5.5.24 **(64 bits)** MSI installer from MySQL Dev. Web Site
- NetBeans IDE 7.2 RC1 with JRE 7 update 5 **(64 bits)** from NetBeans Web Site
- Windows 7 Professional Edition **(64 bits)**

As you can see, all used tools are 64 bits.

My headache starts when I try to include SVN server to the toolset.

Well, before posting this message in this forum, I found many very good SVN solutions for Windows 64 bits such as Visual SVN Server, Subversion Edge from CollabNet and uberSVN from WanDisco. However, all of them install an embedded Apache Server along with SVN Server.

So, as I already have an Apache server working and well configured with all my personal needs, I would totally avoid having two different Apache servers just because of SVN.

I have also searched on the web in order to know whether I could install either VisualSVN or Subversion Edge without their embedded Apache server, but it seems it's not an option.

In my opinion, the only way to use my currently working Apache server is if I could find the SVN binaries for Apache 2.2.22 64bits.

As additional information, also searching many forums on the web, it seems that no SVN 64 bits libraries are released just because there are already good enough free tools in the market for this purpose such as the aforementioned ones. The price is that they also come with the Apache server which I really don't want.

I would fully apreeciate your help in this regard.

Best Regards.

**SOLUTION UPDATE**
Well, fortunately I managed to find Apache Haus web site. They have available Subversion 64 bits binaries ready to integrate with Apache 64 bits.

The setup process is really simple: Just extract the zip file, copy all contents to bin and modules folders inside Apache folder and configure htdocs.conf properly that you are all set.

As additional information, I also found that in order to have a local SVN setup, I really don't need to have a SVN server at all. The only thing I need in this case is to install a 64 bits client.

**FINAL WORD**
Although I don't need SVN server to install subversion on my local environment, I believe it's still worth the lessons learned with this setup and it's still worth to share here on StackOverflow as other guys may need to configure a SVN Server in a Windows 64 bits environment with Apache 64 bits.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Might get better responses from serverfault or superuser

Comment: It's not really good to maintain SVN together with the Apache HTTP Server that is also used for other purpose than SVN. I'd strongly advise to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score -1):

FWIW - Apache in uberSVN is self-contained so you should be fine to use uberSVN and still have your newer version of Apache installed for all your other needs.